# How to map java.time.LocalTime with milliseconds to a java.sql.Time with miliseconds

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-time

How can I convert a `java.time.LocalTime` with fractions of second (micro/milli/nano) to a `java.sql.Time`?

I know that since 2.x version of `spring-data-jpa` those types (JSR310) have their custom converters that maps to legacy `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` but i'm having a lot of problems with the fraction of a second part of a `LocalTime`.

Comment: `LocalTime` doesn't have a format. You can print it however you like.

Comment: Yes i know, the problem isn't the LocalTime @shmosel, the problem is in how to convert from a LocalTime with an specific format to a java.sql.Time

Comment: *"how to convert from a LocalTime **with an specific format**"* Please read first comment again: *`LocalTime` **doesn't have a format***.

Comment: Yes I did ... i'm not explaining myself ... the main question is **How can I convert a LocalTime with fraction of seconds to a java.sql.Time?** That's the question ... @andreas

Comment: Good, then edit the question and ask exactly that, and remove any mention of "format" because neither object has a format.

Comment: haha ok, let me do that :) thanks @andreas

Comment: For which date?  `java.time.LocalTime` has only hours, minutes, seconds and fractions of a second.  But `java.sql.Timestamp` also has year, month and day.  How do you want to chose the year, month and day?

Comment: That's exactly what i don't need ... i just need to save in a column with `time(2)` (postgresql type) the value from the `LocalTime` i have (i.e., _01:10:20.130_)

Comment: I was going to suggest simply calling `Time.valueOf(LocalTime)`, but funnily that loses the milliseonds. [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-) say “ The nanosecond field from LocalTime is not part of the newly created Time object.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to map `java.time.LocalTime` to a `java.sql.Time`

Here is one way to do it without using `String` as intermediate value.

```
java.time.LocalTime localTime = java.time.LocalTime.now();
long epochMilli = localTime.atDate(java.time.LocalDate.EPOCH)
                           .atZone(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault())
                           .toInstant()
                           .toEpochMilli();
java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(epochMilli);

System.out.println(localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(sqlTime));
```

*Output*

```
22:28:22.104
22:28:22.104
```

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate.EPOCH` is unrecognized for me.

Comment: @ManoDestra It is undocumented, but apparently `EPOCH` was added in Java 9.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I'm using Java 8, so that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that a local time represents a particular time during the day:

e.g. 7:30pm

**Not** 7:30pm today or yesterday, or seventeen weeks from Sunday, just ... 7:30pm.

Whereas a java.sql.Time represents a particular time **on a particular day**.

Internally they're stored as a **long** which is the number of milliseconds before or after a particular date (IIRC 1 Jan 1970).

So to convert a LocalTime to a java.sql.Time you have to specify a particular day to which that Time will apply.

Have a look at LocalTime.atDate(LocalDate) which returns a LocalDateTime.

There doesn't seem to be a nice simple way to extract the milliseconds or ***net*** nanoseconds (since 1/1/1970 00:00:00)

Maybe try .toEpochSecond  (requires a time zone to be specified) and then multiply that by either 1000 or 1000000 and write that to the DB and then read it back out (to see whether it worked).

---

Alternately:

You keep saying you don't want the date - I understand, but since the database doesn't, you could try storing localTime.toNanoOfDay.

It will interpret that as a time of the day on 1/1/1970.

Comment: Awesome explanation! thanks :) ... The `.toEpochMilli` solved all the problem!

Comment: You're welcome :D  It's similar to something I've been doing with SQLite, but there it's 'easier' because it doesn't care what the columns are declared as.  Sure, put a String in an Integer field, whatever floats your boat (yikes!).

Comment: From the `java.sql.Time` documentation: “ The date components should be set to the "zero epoch" value of January 1, 1970 and should not be accessed.” So a particular date, yes, but we should regard this as irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that you shouldn’t want to convert from `LocalTime` to the old-fashioned `Time`.

If you think you need a `java.sql.Time` for storing into your SQL database or for a query against it, that may not be the case. Provided that you can use at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2 (or a modern JPA implementation), you can use your `LocalTime` directly against the database and need no conversion. Use for example

```
    yourPreparedStatement.setObject(7, yourLocalTime);
```

Then you’ll be fine.

If you do need a `java.sql.Time`, [Andres’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182660/5772882) shows the right and precise way to convert. The challenge is that the simple `Time.valueOf(LocalTime)` loses the fraction of second. [The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-) say:

> The nanosecond field from LocalTime is not part of the newly created Time object.

It’s clear that you cannot have all the nanoseconds since `Time` only has a precision of milliseconds. Why they didn’t take the milliseconds (the first 3 decimal digits of the 9 digit nanosecond value), I don’t know. Andreas does.